# Getting a different port ERROR in the console while uploading image from the frontend using react js to the Mongo db

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to upload image from my frontend to the mongodb database. Everything works fine with the POSTMAN but whenever I try to upload image from the front end I'm getting a wrong port error in my console log. ( I'm trying to upload the image to the port number 3002 but getting API routing error where the port is showing in 9000. My front end is running on the port 9000 and the backend in the 3002.

This is the file using which i tried to upload the image.

```
import { Avatar, Input } from '@material-ui/core'
import { SettingsInputAntenna } from '@material-ui/icons'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useStateValue } from '../StateProvider'
import './MessageSender.css' 
import FormData from 'form-data'


const MessageSender = () => {
    const [input,setInput]=useState('')
    const [imageUrl,setImageUrl]=useState('')
    const [image,setImage]=useState(null)
    const [{user},dispatch]=useStateValue()

    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        if(e.target.files[0]){
            setImage(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{

        e.preventDefault()

        if(image){
            const imgForm=new FormData()
            imgForm.append('file',image,image.name)


            axios.post('/upload/image',imgForm,{
                headers:{
                    'accept':'application/json',
                    'Accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                    'Content-Type':`multipart/form-data; boundary=${imgForm._boundary}`,
                }
            }).then((res)=>{
                
                console.log(res.data)

                const postData={
                    text: input,
                    imgName: res.data.filename,
                    user:user.displayName,
                    avatar:user.photoURL,
                    timestamp: Date.now()
                }

                console.log(postData)
                savePost(postData)
            }).catch(err=>{

                console.log(err);

            })
        }

        else{
            const postData ={
                text: input,
                user: user.displayName,
                avatar : user.photoURL,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            }

            console.log(postData)
            savePost(postData)
        }

        setImageUrl('')
        setInput('')
        setImage(null)

    }


    const savePost=async(postData)=>{
        await axios.post('/upload/post',postData)
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className='messageSender'>
            <div className='messageSender_top'>
                <div className="avatar_post_class">
                <Avatar src={user.photoURL}/>
                </div>
                
                <form>
                    <div className="post_text">
                    <input type="text" className='messegeSender_input' placeholder="Whats`s up with you ?" value={input} onChange = {(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)}/>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div className="file_selection">
                    <input type="file" id="fileselectionid" className='messeageSender_fileSelector' onChange= {handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="post_button">
                        <button onClick={handleSubmit} type='Submit' id="postbutton"> Post </button>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default MessageSender
```

Axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance=axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3002'
})

export default instance

axios.get('http://localhost:3002/upload/image')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't uploading to port 3002 because you're importing `axios` not `./axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

should be

```
import axios from '<path to axios.js>/axios'
```